# How to create a custom command in Linux for a wine pdf application?

Tags: bash, pdf, wine

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 and would like to have PDFXCview.exe as the standard application to open pdfs. Opening a pdf using a small executable file including

```
#!/bin/bash
wine /foldername/PDFXCview.exe $1
```

works fine. However, I would like to set up "Open with.." properly so that whenever I double-click on a pdf it opens with PDFXCview. Passing this executable seems not to work. How to solve this?

Comment: What desktop environment and file manager are you using?

Comment: 1) You don't need bash here. A more portable POSIX shell will do just fine. 2) You have to quote the argument: `"$1"`. 3) For an answer see here: [How to change the default program for a specific file extension](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41196/12779)

Comment: Also [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94882/how-do-i-set-a-wine-program-ex-foxit-reader-for-windows-as-the-default-progra) might be an answer

Comment: The answer by "To Do" on http://askubuntu.com/questions/94882/how-do-i-set-a-wine-program-ex-foxit-reader-for-windows-as-the-default-progra indeed solved my problem, thank you MattewRock!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the script to

```
#!/bin/sh

QUICKPARLOCATION="c:\\foldername\\PDFXCview.exe"
PARAM=`winepath -w "$*"`
wine "$QUICKPARLOCATION" "$PARAM"
exit 0
```

and adding the program in the "Open with other application-->Use a custom program:" menu, solves the problem.